# The color of my text won't change even though I put it in the code

Tags: css, fonts, colors

I have an H2 with the following code:

```
<h2>
    From Me
</h2>
```

When I try to style it with the following CSS it does not change to the color dark green (#006400).

```
h2{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #006400
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Any reasons why this wouldn't be working?

Thanks!

Comment: why not use firebug or chrome `inspec element` or IE's F12 to inspect.

Answer (score 3):

You have not added "semicolon" after `color`.

Change

```
color: #006400 font-weight: bold;
```

to

```
color: #006400;font-weight: bold;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Yp7/)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're just missing a couple semicolons.

try this

```
h2 { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #006400; font-weight: bold; font-size: 30px; padding: 20px; }
```